# Failed to resolve module specifier when importing Pokemon TCG SDK with javascript

Tags: javascript, api, sdk

I'm trying to make a Pokemon TCG library using the [Pokemon TCG SDK](https://github.com/PokemonTCG/pokemon-tcg-sdk-javascript). I already got my apiKEY and npm install the Javascript implementation on my localhost xampp.

I have my HTML like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TCG</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my script.js like this:

```
import pokemon from 'pokemontcgsdk'

pokemon.configure({apiKey: 'myAPIkey'})

pokemon.card.find('base1-4')
.then(card => {
    console.log(card.name) // "Charizard"
})
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to resolve module specifier "pokemontcgsdk". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I have already tried using "/", "./", or "../" on my import like the one below but it's giving me another error which is 404 error.

```
import pokemon from '../pokemontcgsdk'
```

I have a folder structure like this:

[image: root]

[image: node_modules]

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: https://github.com/WICG/import-maps

Comment: You can publish your `pokemontcgsdk` folder (and any of its dependencies) to your web root and use a `<script type="importmap">`. There is even a [polyfill](https://github.com/guybedford/es-module-shims#import-maps) for import maps.

Comment: Have you tried googling "failed to resolve module specifier"?

Comment: The standard way to do this kind of thing is to use a bundler like [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org), or if you really don't want to understand that the dependency you're trying to import is under the `node_modules/` folder, so you need to be doing `import pokemon from "./node_modules/pokemontgsdk"`. However, that won't actually work because the package you're trying to use doesn't do that, so just use a bundler.

Comment: @code - I have installed webpack using this code`npm i webpack` and then made import like you suggested but I got a new error: `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`. Seriously this is turning into something not worth continuing.

Comment: Not sure if I can help you like that, but I just want you to know that the standard process got developing 99.9% web apps is to use a bundler, and if you don't have it down you won't be going many places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a bundler that will take care of correctly putting together your JS code and its dependencies, you can use ESM URL Imports if your browser supports it.

Since publishing your node_modules might not be the best solution, especially if you want your script to work in production. The best alternative is to **retrieve your dependency from a CDN** like `unpkg.com`

That would look like:

```
import pokemon from 'https://unpkg.com/pokemontcgsdk@2.0.0/es/index.js';

pokemon.configure({apiKey: 'myAPIkey'})

pokemon.card.find('base1-4')
.then(card => {
    console.log(card.name) // "Charizard"
})
```

Comment: I installed webpack like the other commenter but I got an Axios error. I also did what you suggested and it gives me another error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` How are others making it work? Should I try another language other than javascript?

Comment: The Pokemon dependency is likely depending also on other packages. From your error, it looks like it's depending on `axios`.  Now you can begin to see why we use bundlers to manage those dependencies for us. Webpack can be cumbersome to configure (if you haven't configured it properly, you could have errors like you pointed at). If you are beginning in JavaScript, maybe start looking at less configurable bundlers like Parcel.

Comment: Oh my, I installed Parcel and it just works!!! the 'import pokemon from 'pokemontcgsdk';' worked out of the box when I installed Parcel. Not sure why webpack is very hard to setup unlike Pacel which I haven't heard before. Thanks for that!